# Tcl dict create makes weird dictionary

Tags: dictionary, tcl

```
set table [dict create cells state bits state]
set data [dict create 1 "s" 1 "f"]

puts $table
puts $data
```

puts out:

> cells state bits state
>
> 1 f

This is quite weird! why doesn't dict create make a full dictionary on 1 s 1 f ?
thanks!

ps documentation says:

> **dict create** ?*key value ...*?
>   Return a new dictionary that contains each
>   of the key/value mappings listed as arguments (keys and values
>   alternating, with each key being followed by its associated value.)
>   https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm#M6

Post Post Script:
I found that putting any two keys that are the same does the same thing such as:

```
puts [dict create 2 "s" 2 "f"]
```

> 2 f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter different values for the same key (key = 1 in the first case, key = 2 in the second), an associative container like the Tcl `dict` will keep only one of those values.

You can still have a data structure that has multiple equal keys, just don't use `dict create`, which enforces the unique-key trait (that's AFAIK the only reason to initialize dictionaries with `dict create`):

```
% set data {1 s 1 f}
1 s 1 f
% dict get $data 1
f
% set data [dict create 1 s 1 f]
1 f
% dict get $data 1
f
```

Dictionary-handling commands will deal with this structure as if it had only one each of the keys. Dictionary-mutating commands will not preserve the multiple equal keys of the original structure.

Comment: oh duh! of course there can only be one. For some reason I was expecting the dictionary to be like an array of key value pairs (I don't know why I expected that).

Comment: You expected that because of the dual-representation of a dictionary as a string, which does not enforce association. One of the strengths of Tcl, but hard to get use to.